# Safari and all browsers on ios block auth popup

Tags: google-workspace, google-picker

Safari, as well as all browsers on ios, default to blocking all popups.  Unfortunately, this includes the auth popup that first is required for the drive picker to authenticate and then select a google drive file.  Are there workarounds available to ensure browsers do not block this auth popup?  On safari specifically, the first click attempt to launch the auth login modal is blocked, but subsequent clicks are not.